# Regex to parse Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 URI for production and testing with Azurite

Tags: java, regex, azure

In my Java application I am using Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 for storage ([ABFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver)).
In the class that handles the requests to the filesystem, I get a file path as an input and then use some regex to extract Azure connection info from it.

The [Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction-abfs-uri) is in the following format:

```
abfs[s]://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/<file_name>
```

I use the following regex `abfss?://([^/]+)@([^\\.]+)(\\.[^/]+)/?((.+)?)` to parse a given file path to extract:

- fileSystem
- accountName
- accountSuffix
- relativePath (path + file_name)

Below is just a test Java code with comments stating result/value in each variable after matching.

```
private void parsePath(String path) {
    //path = abfs://storage@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/selim/test.csv
    Pattern azurePathPattern = Pattern.compile("abfss?://([^/]+)@([^\\.]+)(\\.[^/]+)/?((.+)?)");
    Matcher matcher = azurePathPattern.matcher(path);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String fileSystem = matcher.group(1); //storage
        String accountName = matcher.group(2); //myaccount
        String accountSuffix = matcher.group(3); //.dfs.core.windows.net
        //relativePath is <path>/<file_name>
        String relativePath = matcher.group(4); //selim/test.csv
    }
}
```

The problem is when I decided to use [Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite) which is an Azure Storage API compatible server (emulator) that allow me to run unit tests against this emulator instead of against an actual Azure Server as recommended in the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio).

Azurite uses a different file URI than Azure so this makes my above Regex invalid for testing purposes. Azurite file URI is in the following format:

```
abfs[s]://<file_system>@<local_ip>:<local_port>/<account_name>/<path>/<file_name>
```

Azurite default `account_name` is **devstoreaccount1** so here is an example path for a file on Azurite:

```
abfs://storage@127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/selim/test.csv
```

If parsed by above regex this will be the output, causing incorrect api calls to Azurite server:

- fileSystem: storage (correct)
- accountName: 127 (incorrect, should be: **devstoreaccount1**)
- accountSuffix: .0.0.1:10000 (incorrect, should be **empty string**)
- relativePath: devstoreaccount1/selim/test.csv (incorrect, should be **selim/test.csv**)

Is it possible to have a 1 regex that can handle both URIs or 2 regexes to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use a single pattern for this, but you will need to check which group matched in the code to determine where the necessary details are captured.

The regex will look like

```
abfss?://(?:([^@/]*)@(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}:\d+)/([^/]+)|([^/]+)@([^.]+)(\.[^/]+))(?:/(.+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfRaNe/2). The `([^@/]*)@(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}:\d+)/([^/]+)` alternative allows capturing the file system, the IP address like part (with port number) after `@`, and the account name after a slash.

The [Java code](https://ideone.com/AMa1yM) will look like

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abfss?://(?:([^@/]*)@(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3}:\\d+)/([^/]+)|([^/]+)@([^.]+)(\\.[^/]+))(?:/(.+))?");
        String[] inputs = {
            "abfs://storage@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/selim/test.csv",
            "abfs://storage@127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/selim/test.csv"
        };
        for (String s: inputs) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.find()){
                if (matcher.group(5) != null) { // If original URL is found
                    String fileSystem = matcher.group(4); //storage
                    String accountName = matcher.group(5); //myaccount
                    String accountSuffix = matcher.group(6); //.dfs.core.windows.net
                    String relativePath = matcher.group(7); //selim/test.csv
                    System.out.println(s + ":\nfileSystem: " + fileSystem + "\naccountName: " + accountName + "\naccountSuffix: '" + accountSuffix + "'\nrelativePath:" + relativePath + "\n-----");
                } else { // we have an Azurite URL
                    String fileSystem = matcher.group(1); //storage
                    String accountName = matcher.group(3); //devstoreaccount1
                    String accountSuffix = ""; // empty (or do you need matcher.group(2) to get "127.0.0.1:10000"?)
                    String relativePath = matcher.group(7); //selim/test.csv
                    System.out.println(s + ":\nfileSystem: " + fileSystem + "\naccountName: " + accountName + "\naccountSuffix: '" + accountSuffix + "'\nrelativePath:" + relativePath + "\n-----");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abfs://storage@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/selim/test.csv:
fileSystem: storage
accountName: myaccount
accountSuffix: '.dfs.core.windows.net'
relativePath:selim/test.csv
-----
abfs://storage@127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/selim/test.csv:
fileSystem: storage
accountName: devstoreaccount1
accountSuffix: ''
relativePath:selim/test.csv
```

**Solution 2**

You can use two different regular expressions and if the first one does not find a match, the second will be tried. The first one:

```
abfss?://([^@/]*)@(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}:\d+)/([^/]+)(?:/(.+))?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfRaNe/3). The second one:

```
abfss?://([^/]+)@([^.]+)(\.[^/]+)(?:/(.+))?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfRaNe/4). As this one also matches URLs of the first type, you need to make sure you run them in the fixed order.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tdHzQE):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern pattern_azurite = Pattern.compile("abfss?://([^@/]*)@(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3}:\\d+)/([^/]+)(?:/(.+))?");
        Pattern pattern_original = Pattern.compile("abfss?://([^/]+)@([^.]+)(\\.[^/]+)(?:/(.+))?");
        String[] inputs = {
            "abfs://storage@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/selim/test.csv",
            "abfs://storage@127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/selim/test.csv",
            "http://www.blahblah.blah"
        };
        for (String s: inputs) {
            Map<String, String> result = null;
            Matcher matcher_azurite = pattern_azurite.matcher(s);
            if (matcher_azurite.find()){
                result = parseMatchResult(matcher_azurite, new int[] {1, 3, -1, 4});
            } else {
                Matcher matcher_original = pattern_original.matcher(s);
                if (matcher_original.find()){
                    result = parseMatchResult(matcher_original, new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4});
                }
            }
            if (result != null) {                        // Now print
                for (String key : result.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println("'" + key + "': '" + result.get(key) + "'");
                }
                System.out.println("----------------");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No match!");
            }
            
        }
    }
    public static Map<String, String> parseMatchResult(Matcher m, int[] indices) {
        Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<String, String>();
        res.put("fileSystem", m.group(indices[0]));
        res.put("accountName", m.group(indices[1]));
        res.put("accountSuffix", indices[2] > -1 ? m.group(indices[2]) : "");
        res.put("relativePath", m.group(indices[3]));
        return res;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'fileSystem': 'storage'
'accountSuffix': '.dfs.core.windows.net'
'accountName': 'myaccount'
'relativePath': 'selim/test.csv'
----------------
'fileSystem': 'storage'
'accountSuffix': ''
'accountName': 'devstoreaccount1'
'relativePath': 'selim/test.csv'
----------------
No match!
```

Comment: thanks, the code works but the idea is to avoid the if (whichUrlProvided) to avoid changing the production code to check if this is a testRun then do this. We want to have 1 generic handling or to make our parser be able to handle both URIs without checking if this is a test URI. What do you think?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa It is not possible with Java regex that does not support branch reset groups. Either use this single regex approach, or use two different patterns.

Comment: So in both cases we need to have some if condition to check on the URL, either use 1 regex and check on matcher.group() or from beginning check if url has ip-port use regex1 else use regex2 right? 
I will do some unit tests on your regex method before marking as correct answer. If you have any other ideas please let me know

Comment: @SelimAlawwa I have already thought and tried various patterns, and this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: OK thanks, I will do some tests to ensure its solid. But I mean as a non-regex solution do you think of any possible approaches?

Comment: @SelimAlawwa Sorry, no.

Comment: Can you change your answer to support 2 different regexes one for each url and make if regex1 find() else use regex 2 it will be more clear

Comment: @SelimAlawwa But the details will still be in different groups, is it fine? Ok, I have an idea.

Comment: There is a problem here, for production performance, it's better to have the `pattern_original ` match first and if failed try the azurite, but If I do this both will match for pattern_original and azurite wont be used.

Comment: @SelimAlawwa Then use `"abfss?://([^/]+)@(?!\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3}:\\d)([^.]+)(\\.[^/]+)(?:/(.+))?"`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfRaNe/6).